# php PDOStatement->execute() not enough memory

Tags: php

code:

```
    $list = $this->with([
        'paper_base',
        'last_score'    => function ($query) use ($module_id) {
            $query->whereUserId(request()->mid)->whereModuleId($module_id)->order(['answer_times' => 'DESC']);
        },
        'highest_score' => function ($query) use ($module_id) {
            $query->whereModuleId($module_id);
        }
    ])->withCount([
        'has_bought'   => 'has_bohas_signupught',
        'has_signup'   => '',
        'signup'       => 'signup_num',
        'paper_answer' => function ($query, &$alias) use ($module_id) {
            $query->whereUserId(request()->mid)->whereModuleId($module_id);
            $alias = 'post_times';
        }
    ])->where($map)->field('paper_id,price')->paginate($this->getListRows())
```

## **ERROR MESSAGE**

> ```
> {
>         "name": "think\\exception\\ErrorException",
>         "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/topthink/think-orm/src/db/PDOConnection.php",
>         "line": 770,
>         "code": 1,
>         "message": "Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 323584 bytes)",
>         "trace": [
>             {
>                 "function": "appShutdown",
>                 "class": "think\\initializer\\Error",
>                 "type": "->",
>                 "args": []
>             }
>         ],
>         "source": {
>             "first": 761,
>             "source": [
>                 "\n",
>                 "            // 参数绑定\n",
>                 "            if ($procedure) {\n",
>                 "                $this->bindParam($bind);\n",
>                 "            } else {\n",
>                 "                $this->bindValue($bind);\n",
>                 "            }\n",
>                 "\n",
>                 "            // 执行查询\n",
>                 "            $this->PDOStatement->execute();\n",
>                 "\n",
>                 "            // SQL监控\n",
>                 "            if (!empty($this->config['trigger_sql'])) {\n",
>                 "                $this->trigger('', $master);\n",
>                 "            }\n",
>                 "\n",
>                 "            $this->reConnectTimes = 0;\n",
>                 "\n",
>                 "            return $this->PDOStatement;\n"
>             ]
>         }
>     }
> ```

Set `ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');` doesn't work?

Comment: This seems to be a problem with the Think ORM, I guess it's trying to store the entire response to the query and running out of memory.

Comment: Thanks for your question. The problem has been found, I configured php_admin_value[memory_limit]=32M in php-fpm.conf. It cannot be overridden by using ini_set('memory_limit', '256M') in the index.php file.